# combobox c# displaymember valuemember dataset

Tags: c#, combobox, dataset

```
Category ctg = new Category();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = ctg.query(_conn);
cbCategory.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cbCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbCategory.ValueMember = "ID";
```

in this case output : 

displaymember->valuemember
e->1
d->2
c->3
a->4
b->5

when i sort from properties combobox
a->1
b->2
c->3
d->4
e->5

what i want
a->4
b->5
c->3
d->2
e->1

anyone can help me?? what code i must add, without change any query sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by sorting DataTable

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "Name asc";
cbCategory.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  private void btnReverse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
        foreach (var i in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }



        list.Reverse();
        comboBox1.DataSource = list;


    }
```

Comment: sorry the data not reverse, it's random